# Convert Estimator to TPUEstimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-estimator

Is it possible to convert an `Estimator` to a `TPUEstimator` in TensorFlow without significant effort in rewriting its functions? I have a model in `Estimator` form that works nicely on a CPU, but I don't know a convenient way to convert it to a `TPUEstimator` without having to rewrite the `model_fn` and `input_fn`.

The reason this requires significant work to do manually is that I am using Keras to create my model, and then the following helper function to create the `Estimator`:

```
   my_keras_model.compile(
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9),
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metric='accuracy')
   estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=my_keras_model)
```

It would be great if I could do something like `estimator.to_TPU_estimator()` or something like that -- perhaps someone knows of a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There can't be such a function, because `model_fn` specification is different in two estimators. Some differences are pretty deep, such as this one (from [TPU tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.6/programmers_guide/using_tpu)):

> When training on a cloud TPU you **must** wrap the optimizer in a
>   `tf.contrib.tpu.CrossShardOptimizer`, which uses an `allreduce` to
>   aggregate gradients and broadcast the result to each shard (each TPU
>   core).

And it means patching the internals of keras optimizer and update ops.

The recommended way to is to have different `model_fn` wrappers for GPU and TPU model and it seems the fastest way for you. In your case, it means rewriting keras [`model_to_estimator`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/estimator.py#L147) function for TPU estimator.

---

The first and simplest approximation is this:

```py
def model_to_estimator(keras_model=None,
                       keras_model_path=None,
                       custom_objects=None,
                       model_dir=None,
                       config=None):
  keras_weights = keras_model.get_weights()
  keras_model_fn = _create_keras_tpu_model_fn(keras_model, custom_objects)
  est = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator(keras_model_fn, model_dir=model_dir, config=config)
  _save_first_checkpoint(keras_model, est, custom_objects, keras_weights)
  return est
```

Here, `_save_first_checkpoint` call is actually optional, but if you'd like to keep it, import this function from `tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.estimator`.

---

The real work happens in `_create_keras_tpu_model_fn` function, which replaces [`_create_keras_model_fn`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/estimator.py#L147). The changes are:

- the internal *tensorflow* optimizer must be wrapped with `CrossShardOptimizer` as mentioned earlier, and
- the inner function must return `TPUEstimatorSpec`.

It is possible that few more lines must be patched as well, but it looks ok to me. A complete version is below:

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.estimator import _save_first_checkpoint, _clone_and_build_model

def model_to_estimator(keras_model=None,
                       keras_model_path=None,
                       custom_objects=None,
                       model_dir=None,
                       config=None):
  keras_weights = keras_model.get_weights()
  keras_model_fn = _create_keras_tpu_model_fn(keras_model, custom_objects)
  est = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator(keras_model_fn, model_dir=model_dir, config=config)
  _save_first_checkpoint(keras_model, est, custom_objects, keras_weights)
  return est


def _create_keras_tpu_model_fn(keras_model, custom_objects=None):

  def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    """model_fn for keras Estimator."""
    model = _clone_and_build_model(mode, keras_model, custom_objects, features,
                                   labels)
    predictions = dict(zip(model.output_names, model.outputs))

    loss = None
    train_op = None
    eval_metric_ops = None

    # Set loss and metric only during train and evaluate.
    if mode is not tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
      model.optimizer.optimizer = tf.contrib.tpu.CrossShardOptimizer(model.optimizer.optimizer)

      model._make_train_function()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
      loss = model.total_loss

      if model.metrics:
        eval_metric_ops = {}
        # When each metric maps to an output
        if isinstance(model.metrics, dict):
          for i, output_name in enumerate(model.metrics.keys()):
            metric_name = model.metrics[output_name]
            if callable(metric_name):
              metric_name = metric_name.__name__
            # When some outputs use the same metric
            if list(model.metrics.values()).count(metric_name) > 1:
              metric_name += '_' + output_name
            eval_metric_ops[metric_name] = tf.metrics.mean(
                model.metrics_tensors[i - len(model.metrics)])
        else:
          for i, metric_name in enumerate(model.metrics):
            if callable(metric_name):
              metric_name = metric_name.__name__
            eval_metric_ops[metric_name] = tf.metrics.mean(
                model.metrics_tensors[i])

    if mode is tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
      train_op = model.train_function.updates_op

    return tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        predictions=predictions,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=train_op,
        eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)

  return model_fn
```